# Continuation principle for solutions of Floer's equation in $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ and transversality

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

Consider $(M,\omega)$ a symplectic manifold and $J$ a compatible almost complex structure. For me it's well known that if we consider 2 solutions $u,v:\mathbb{R}\times S^1\rightarrow M$ of Floer's equation

$$\partial_su+J(u)(\partial_tu+\nabla H_t(u))=0$$

we will have that if $\{(s,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times S^1: u(s,t)=v(s,t)\}$ is not a discrete set, then $u=v$. This is essentially a consequence of Carleman's similarity principle.

Now if we consider the Floer equation for maps $u:\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ with Lagrangian boundary conditions $u(\mathbb{R}\times \{0\})\subset L_0, u(\mathbb{R}\times \{1\})\subset L_1$ will we have the same property ?
Following the proof of the previous statement we can prove that if is not a discrete set on $\mathbb{R}\times (0,1)$ , then using the Carleman Similarity principle and the fact that soliutions are $C^{\infty}$, in particular continuous, then $u=v$. However can be say anything about in $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$? In this case we could have something strange hapenning with the points $C:=\{0,\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ , and we would have that this $C$ is not a discrete set of $[0,1]$ but is of $(0,1)$. Hence I am not sure we can make the same claim in this case ?

The reason I am interested in this, is because in order to obtain a family of almost complex structures such that the Floer map is transversal to the zero section, in the periodic case one fisrt proves that the set of regular points $R(u)$ is open and dense and some sort of Continuation principle. However to prove that $R(u)$ is dense I think we might need some sort of property like I mentioned before.

Any enlightment is appreciated, thanks in advance.